# Getting special characters for currency symbol when deployed on tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

On deploying my code on tomcat I am getting a special character(�) for currency symbol.

Comment: Check browser/page/servlet response character encoding. Be more specific please.

Comment: Hi Jesus , I have developed my code using jdeveloper. I have .jsff pages over here.Any configuration need to be done at tomcat level?

Comment: Check this: https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding

Comment: try changing to encoding="ISO-8859-1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two easy steps :

- Check the (physical) encoding of your JSPs files ; set  it to UTF-8 (check the file properties in your IDE)
- Specify that encoding too in the `<head>` section of the HTML page :

For HTML5 :

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

For older versions :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Comment: Hi Olivier, I am using jsff pages.. added UTF-8 still I am facing the same old issue.

Comment: Hi Olivier, Any configuration need to be done at tomcat level?

Comment: Please ensure that the file is *physically* encoded in UTF-8 ; simply adding the header isn't enough, it would be like saying "I will speak in Japanese" while still speaking german, for example.

Comment: No configuration needed in Tomcat.

Comment: Still facing the same issue..Any db changes need to be made?

Comment: You may want to verify which encoding your database uses, indeed. 
If a symbol has been saved in the database, and that database uses an encoding that cannot properly encode your currency symbol, you will get garbage out of the database - and then to the screen, whatever the encoding of your JSF pages be.

Comment: Checked..It's utf8

Answer (score 0):

You have a few general settings with different impact levels:

(1) Configure your JSP page to display content in utf-8 (place on top of jsp page)

`<%@page pageEncoding="utf-8" %>`

(2) Set default character encoding to utf-8 (java system property)

`-Dfile.encoding="utf-8"`

(3) Configure your application server to encode request parameters in utf-8 (in conf/server.xml)

`<connector .... URIEncoding="utf-8" />`

(4) Tell browser content is in utf-8 (place in html HEAD section)

`<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />`

Comment: Hi Mayur, My code is working fine when deployed on weblogic..But facing issue when deployed on tomcat..